# /boot partition is always full

Tags: boot, partitioning, disk-usage

My /boot partition is always full after a few updates. I had always to delete the old version of the following files to regain some diskspace:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1271689 Nov  6 21:34 abi-3.19.0-xx-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   177782 Nov  6 21:34 config-3.19.0-xx-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 32608396 Nov 11 20:23 initrd.img-3.19.0-xx-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3622220 Nov  6 21:34 System.map-3.19.0-xx-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  6623936 Nov  6 21:34 vmlinuz-3.19.0-xx-generic
```

Is this normal or is there something wrong with my installation?

Additional informations:

```
    # du -h /boot
    12K /boot/lost+found
    2.4M    /boot/grub/fonts
    2.1M    /boot/grub/i386-pc
    126K    /boot/grub/locale
    6.8M    /boot/grub
    93M /boot

    # df -h /boot
    Dateisystem    Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
    /dev/sdb1       236M     95M  130M   43% /boot
```

Comment: Can you append the outputs of `du -h /boot` and `df -h /boot` to your question?

Comment: sure, done. It looks fine to me right now. But I have just delete some "old" files.

Comment: have you ever tried `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`?

Comment: Yeah, but it does not affect any files on my /boot partition.

Comment: Strange.  My /boot contains only about 60 MB, and the `autoremove` just took out kernel 4.2.0-17 and it's related dependancies.

Comment: nope, just checked it, not a single files was touched/removed :( The permissions on the files look good to me. And there also no errors during autoremove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution for you in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100733/why-arent-old-linux-images-removed-when-installing-new-kernel-updates), or [this even older question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

The basic suggestion of both is to use Ubuntu Tweak or Synaptic package manager to help with limiting the number of old kernels in the system.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that! I was about to write my own script. :) Thanks for this! But then its true that apt-get autoremove dont removes those old kernel files?

Comment: It does remove them for me, but it may be either that I'm on 15.10, or that I've always used the autoremove function rather than deleteing the files by hand.